# How to use GeoScript groovy library inside Java project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

I have spring/postgis service with some spatial capabilities, but I haven't found Java library that can [interpolate](http://geoscript.org/groovy/api/geoscript/geom/LineString.html#interpolatePoint(double)) point to a linestring.

I'd like to to use this geoscript library to do that, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I've read about how to dynamically load groovy class in Java code, but I'm not sure how to do that with external library code. Should I just add this geoscript to build.gradle?
Or maybe there is some more efficient ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I just gave it a try and it worked flawlessly. In the end a compiled Groovy library is just Java byte code.

Citing from Groovy in Action, Chapter 1.1.2 Playing nicely with Java: seamless integration:

> Groovy is only
>   a new way of creating ordinary Java classes—
>   from a runtime perspective, Groovy is Java
>   with an additional JAR file as a dependency.

So add these dependencies

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5'
compile 'org.geoscript:geoscript-groovy:1.6.0'
```

and this repository

```
maven {
    url "http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main"
}
```

to your gradle build file and you are good to go.

This is the Java code I tried:

```
import geoscript.geom.LineString;
import geoscript.geom.Point;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LineString line = new LineString(new Point(1,2), new Point(3,4), new Point(4,5));
        Point point = line.interpolatePoint(0.5);
        System.out.println(point); // printed POINT (2.5 3.5)
    }

}
```